# Dynamic post entry

Tags: vue.js, dynamic, get, vue-component

I'm trying to create pagination for my site on Vue.js.
I have two buttons:

```
<button @click.prevent="onPrevBtnClick">previous</button>
<button @click.prevent="onNextBtnClick">next</button>
```

Which pass to my main component:

```
methods: {
    onPrevBtnClick () {
      this.$emit('prev-button')
    },
    onNextBtnClick () {
      this.$emit('next-button')
    }
  }
```

Basically, I want to make a query according to currentPage

```
async fetchMovies () {
  try {
    const fetchData = await axios.get(`${process.env.VUE_APP_API_URL}/discover/movie&api_key=${process.env.VUE_APP_API_KEY}&page=${this.currentPage}`)
    this.movies = {...fetchData.data.results}
  }
  catch (e) {
    console.log(e)
  }
},
async onPrevBtnClick () {
  this.currentPage--
},
async onNextBtnClick () {
  this.currentPage++
}
```

I try to change them through a method, also tried through the computed but for some reason will not change dynamically.

I will be grateful for your help.

Comment: So the pagination component is emitting and the parent component is supposed to respond to the emitted event by changing `this.currentPage`? What specifically are you expecting that isn't happening?

Answer (score 0):

If you want `this.movies` to be updated when the user clicks "previous" or "next" you'll have to call the `fetchMovies` method in the `onPrevBtnClick` and `onNextBtnClick` methods. Currently `onPrevBtnClick` and `onNextBtnClick` only update `this.currentPage`, but doing so will not automatically cause `fetchMovies` to execute if `fetchMovies` is a method.

An alternative approach would be to make `this.movies` a computed property that is based on `this.currentPage` and get rid of `fetchMovies`, putting that logic in the computed property.

Check out the guide on [Computed Properties and Watchers](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html) for more information. The key things to understand are:

1. "computed properties are cached based on their reactive dependencies. A computed property will only re-evaluate when some of its reactive dependencies have changed."
2. Methods never reevaluate on their own like computed properties. Methods need you to explicitly call them.